# Accessing action payload data inside map after piping it with mergeMap for API call in ngrx effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am working on an `Angular 6` project with `NGRX 6.01`.

```
@Effect()
deleteRole$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<DeleteRoleRequestedAction>(RoleActionTypes.DeleteRoleRequested),
    mergeMap(action => this.rolesService.deleteRole(action.payload.id)),
    map((response) => {
        return new DeleteRoleSuccessAction({ id: response.id });
    })
);
```

As in the above code, I am catching the API call for deleting a role in effects and calling API service for deleting a role using `mergeMap`. After that I am returning the id of the deleted role using `map`. I won't be getting the id of the deleted role in this particular request. So what I want to do is, after the role is successfully deleted I have to return the `DeleteRoleSuccessAction` with `id` from action payload of `RoleActionTypes.DeleteRoleRequested`. Is there any method to get the action payload of `RoleActionTypes.DeleteRoleRequested` inside the map operator?

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks man. Why don't you post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return desired result from your `deleteRole` call through `map` operator:

```
this.rolesService.deleteRole(action.payload.id)
   .pipe(map(() => action.payload)
```